# Unlink deleting more than just the files passed to it

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm creating an SQL file, placing this file into a zip file with some images and then deleting the SQL file with unlink.Strange thing is it deletes the zip file as well.

```
if (file_put_contents($sqlFileName, $sql) !== false) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open($workingDir . $now . '.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
            $zip->addFile($sqlFileName, basename($sqlFileName));
            if(! empty($images)) {
                foreach ($images as $image) {
                    $zip->addFile($imagesDir . $image, $image);
                }
            }
        }
        unlink($sqlFileName);
}
```

Comment: Very hardly - unlink() can't delete more than a file at a time. I bet the zip file never gets created.

Comment: You're not calling `$zip->close()`. Not sure if this is causing your problem, but it seems like a good idea.

Comment: Instead of creating a file from a string, then adding it to the `ZipArchive`, you can also use `$zip->addFromString()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfromstring.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfromstring.php:

> jared at kippage dot com  03-Sep-2009 01:08
>
> It may seem a little obvious to
>   some but it was an oversight on my
>   behalf.
>
> If you are adding files to the zip
>   file that you want to be deleted make
>   sure you delete AFTER you call the
>   close() function.
>
> **If the files added to the object
>   aren't available at save time the zip
>   file will not be created.**

The simple solution: Add `$zip->close()` before you call `unlink($sqlFileName);` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`unlink()` *never* deletes more than one file. Your zip file isn't created in the first place, because you don't close the archive - which basically tells PHP to wrap up the archive's headers, do the compression, etc. Append `$zip->close()` to your code.

**UPDATE** I just read that ZipArchive::close() is called automatically at the end of the script, so this leaves just two options: Either your call to `zip->open()` fails. or your code isn't entering the foreach loop - leaving you with an empty archive. Empty archives do not get created according to [a comment in the function's doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-close.php#78667).

Comment: Although zip close is called at the end of the script automatically, because I'm deleting a resource before I close the zip, the zip doesn't get created